# Powershell to automate web site testing with modal dialog

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, powershell, showmodaldialog

Working on a quick Powershell script to use the IE object to enter values and submit a web page with a modal dialog. I want to be able to invoke the modal dialog, check some boxes on the dialog, and then close it and return to the page. I can invoke the modal dialog but nothing executes after the line to invoke the dialog until it is closed.

Powershell

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.visible = $true

$ie.navigate($url); do {sleep 1} until (-not ($ie.Busy)) 

$doc = $ie.Document
$books = $doc.getElementById(“searchBooks”).click();
```

Javascript

```
var ret = window.showModalDialog('selectBooks.aspx, books, ...);
```

I need a way to invoke commands in the context of the dialog.  Tried running in the background and creating a runspace but no joy with either solution

```
& {$books = $doc.getElementById(“searchBooks”).click();}
```

(blocking)

```
$rs = [Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspace()
$rs.Open()

$rs.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("doc", $doc)
$p = $rs.CreatePipeline( { $books = $doc.getElementById(“searchBooks”).click(); } )
$p.Input.Close()
$p.InvokeAsync()
```

(not blocking, but I didn't have a handle to dialog elements)

Answer (score 0):

That's an expected behavior of the *modal* dialog. If you want to interact with a dialog, perhaps [`showModelessDialog()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536761%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) is what you want.

Comment: Yes I understand the meaning of modal; that should be evident from two  solutions I tried